# Approximate Order-Preserving Huffman Code

Tags: c, algorithm, priority-queue, huffman-code, min-heap

I am working on an assignment for an Algorithms and Data Structures class. I am having trouble understanding the instructions given. I will do my best to explain the problem.

The input I am given is a positive integer *n* followed by *n* positive integers which represent the frequency (or weight) for symbols in an ordered character set. The first goal is to construct a tree that gives an approximate order-preserving Huffman code for each character of the ordered character set. We are to accomplish this by "greedily merging the two *adjacent* trees whose weights have the smallest sum."

In the assignment we are shown that a conventional Huffman code tree is constructed by first inserting the weights into a priority queue. Then by using a delmin() function to "pop" off the root from the priority queue I can obtain the two nodes with the lowest frequencies and merge them into one node with its left and right being these two lowest frequency nodes and its priority being the sum of the priorities of its children. This merged node then is inserted back into the min-heap. The process is repeated until all input nodes have been merged. I have implemented this using an array of size 2*n*-1 with the input nodes being from 0...*n*-1 and then from *n*...2*n*-1 being the merged nodes.

I do not understand how I can greedily merge the two adjacent trees whose weights have the smallest sum. My input has basically been organized into a min-heap and from there I must find the two adjacent nodes that have the smallest sum and merge them. By adjacent I assume my professor means that they are next to each other in the input.

Example Input:

```
9
1
2
3
3
2
1
1
2
3
```

Then my min-heap would look like so:

```
               1
          /         \
        2            1 
     /     \        /  \
    2       2      3    1
   /  \
  3    3
```

The two adjacent trees (or nodes) with the smallest sum, then, are the two consecutive 1's that appear near the end of the input. What logic can I apply to start with these nodes? I seem to be missing something but I can't quite grasp it. Please, let me know if you need any more information. I can elaborate myself or provide the entire assignment page if something is unclear.

Comment: Did not realize I needed to tag homework. Just found out.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be done with a small modification to the conventional algoritm. Instead of storing single trees in your priority queue heap, store pairs of adjacent trees. Then, at each step you remove the minimum pair `(t1, t2)` as well as the up to two pairs that also contain those trees, i.e. `(u, t1)` and `(t2, r)`. Then merge `t1` and `t2` to a new tree `t'`, re-insert the pairs `(u, t')` and `(t', r)` in the heap with updated weights and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pop two trees and make 3rd tree. To it left node join tree with smaller sum and to right node join second tree. Put this tree to heap. From your example

Pop 2 tree from heap:

> 1 1

Make tree

```
  ?
 / \
?   ?
```

Put smaller tree to left node

```
min(1, 1) = 1

  ?
 / \
1   ?
```

Put to right node second tree

```
  ?
 / \
1   1
```

Tree you made have sum = sum of left node + sum of right node

```
  2
 / \
1   1
```

Put new tree (sum 2) to heap.

Finally you will have one tree, It's Huffman tree.